# About a character of group rep

Tags: representation-theory

We know that a character of a group representation has the same value for conjugate elements, my question is: are the elements which have the same character, conjugate?or it's not necessary?! thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by " same character conjugate"?

Comment: ((Two elements g, h in G are conjugate in G if and only if
x(g) = x(h) for every irreducible character of G)). is this sentence right? 
Is this condition necessary and sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume we are working over ${\mathbb C}$. Given a finite group $G$, the irreducible characters of $G$ form a basis of the space $\{f: G\to {\mathbb C}\ |\ \forall g, x\in G: f(g) = f(xgx^{-1})\}$ of class functions on $G$. In particular, if $x,y\in G$ have equal images under all irreducible characters, they have equal images under all class functions, and so they belong to the same conjugacy class.

Comment: Got it! thanks alot.